# listen to click event JS

Tags: javascript, haxe

I tried to listen to click event in Haxe/JS:

```
static function main()
{
    var initHandler:Dynamic = init;        
    Browser.window.onload = initHandler;
}

static private function init()
{
    var clickHandler:Dynamic = learnBtn;    
    Browser.document.getElementById("readMoreBtn").addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
}

static private function learnBtn()
{
}
```

I'm really need all this?

Why i can't do this (without `initHandler` and `clickHandler`):

```
Browser.window.onload = init;
```

OR

```
Browser.document.getElementById("readMoreBtn").addEventListener("click", learnBtn);
```

2. The JS file not loaded after all the HTML? I can to define that?
3. It's not related to this topic but I tried to google and search in Haxe.org but nothing. what it is "untyped" keyword.

Comment: i find this very help:https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/haxelang/GSck15Jebh8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `Dynamic` intermediary variable indirectly solves your problem but you should try understanding the compiler error message.

**What the compiler says:**

If you write:

```
function init() {
   // do stuff on window.onload
}

Browser.window.onload = init;
```

the compiler will tell you:

```
Test.hx:22: characters 68-117 : Void -> Void should be js.html.EventListener
Test.hx:22: characters 68-117 : Void -> Void should be Dynamic -> Void
```

What does that mean? It means that your function `init()`, which has a `Void->Void` signature, should be `js.html.EventListener`, which [is defined as](http://api.haxe.org/js/html/EventListener.html) `Dynamic->Void`.

**The right code:**

In other words you `init()` function should have an argument so it should be declared as:

```
function init(event:Dynamic) {
   // do stuff on window.onload
}
```

**Forcing the compiler**

You can tell the compiler to let you write possibly incorrect (but we know valid) code:

```
var foo:Dynamic = init;
Browser.window.onload = foo; // always happy

Browser.window.onload = untyped init; // do not type, please

Browser.window.onload = cast init; // I'm sure I'm right
```